# Is it possible to dynamically modify the style of a child element (with no id) in a div (with id)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, svg

With the following code:

```
<div id="container">
    <svg [attributes etc.]> ... </svg>
</div>
```

I would like to **dynamically change the width and height of the SVG**.

I have tried:

```
myObj = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('svg');
myObj.style.width = "400px";
```

but I get the error "undefined is not an object".

**The SVG is loaded using a server-side include**, and I can not modify it in any way, so I need to find a way to manipulate it from the outside.

I would prefer to avoid jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementsByTagName returns the array-like collection object. So, you need to iterate over the collection for eg:

```
myObj = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('svg');
myObj[0].style.width = "400px";//myObj[0] refers to first found svg element
```

Comment: It worked great, and I will choose your answer when it becomes possible in a minute. Do you know if there is there a better choice (ie more direct) like "document.getElementById('container').child(0)?

Comment: you may use `document.querySelector('#container > svg').style.width = '400px';`

Answer (score 4):

The reason you get that error is because `myObj`, the result of `getElementsByTagName()`, is a NodeList of elements since it can potentially return more than one element, and `style` is not defined on a NodeList. Not a particularly helpful error since it doesn't describe the actual problem...

Anyway, simply index off of that collection to get an element that you can work with:

```
myObj = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('svg');
myObj[0].style.width = "400px";
```

Alternatively, if you're sure you will only ever have one `#container > svg`, use `querySelector()` instead:

```
myObj = document.querySelector('#container > svg');
myObj.style.width = "400px";
```

Comment: I have read that querySelector is MUCH slower than getElementById, so I have tried to avoid it.

Comment: @Andrew Swift: I suggest running a benchmark to verify that before you decide if it's not worth considering.

Comment: How often are you going to select this element? I am sure the SVG needs more time to render than this element is selected.

Comment: I just select it once, to resize it to the window size. It's true there's not a huge loss there, but the page is already too slow to load so I'm trying to optimize every little thing.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to acheive this with css alone, providing you have access to that?

```
#container {
    svg {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't really dynamic though.

Comment: The problem is that I need to do it with Javascript. The value is generate as the page loads, and I don't know it ahead of time.

Comment: Sorry I completely missed the dynamic bit - no idea how. You want to avoid using jQuery? Could you set up a jsFiddle?